# Excel: Find the Position/Location of Each Occurrence of a Specific Word in a String in a Column

Tags: excel-formula, position, multiple-columns

Using an MS Excel formula, I would like to find the Position(s)/Location of specific words found within a String of text located in a Range/Column of cells.

I'm using a formula that only identifies and finds the position(s) of a keyword by a single cell versus a column. I'm not able to repeat this action by looking throughout the column cells, using my numeric helper column (Cell D2:D12 "Occurrence") which provides the occurrence of the next position to be found.

Helper columns are welcomed if necessary to achieve the desired results.

[image]

The cells highlighted in "Red" is what I'm looking for as the final output results.

See below for formulas used for Column C and D.  Text string is located in Column A2:A12.

[image]

COLUMN A
DATA TEXT
Dolly would not count her eggs but Count her apples
Tony drove a pickup truck to work
Over many nights he could not sleep
Only this and nothing more
She went by to pickup her son
To many times he would count over
They went shopping for Christmas
You can count him to pickup someone
They count so much they would sleep in his pickup
Nobody would play with Timmy
Trying to find the position location of each word

COLUMN B
Keyword List
Toe
Shoe
Count
Pumpkin
Pickup
Randy
Sally
Sleep
Jonathan

C2: `=SUMPRODUCT((LEN($A$2:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER($A$2:$A$12)),UPPER(B2),"")))/LEN(B2))`
D2&E2: `=FILTER(B2:C10,C2:C10>0)`
F2: `=IF(E2="","",REPT(D2&"^",E2))`
G2: `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,F2:F4)`
H2: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($G$2,"^",REPT(" ",LEN($G$2))),(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,"<>&""")-1)*LEN($G$2)+1,LEN($G$2)))`
I2:  `=IF(H2="","",IF(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,H2)>1,SUM(I1+1),1))`

Comment: try tweaking this : https://exceljet.net/formula/find-nth-occurrence-of-character

Comment: Could you share the formulas in columns `C` and `D`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with formulas. I could only do it in VBA. I would need the Keyword column and the Data Text column to create the three additional columns. As you add or remove a Keyword or add/remove a Data Text, the data in the three columns would get updated. If that is of interest to you, do confirm or just add the `VBA` tag to your question. Otherwise just ignore.

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, Thank you for your assistance, I've provided additional info with the formulas I've used to achieve up to this point.  The ultimate end solution to my project is to allow excel to identify and extract specific keywords from the text string based on using the relative position and location of multiple keywords within the content of each cell by column and row where keyword is found.  I'd much prefer an Excel formula vs. VBA if at all possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below picture set up and formulas solution as in.

1] `C2` "Total occurrence", formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A$2:$A$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER($A$2:$A$12),LOWER(B2),"")))/LEN(B2)
```

2] `D2` "Count", formula copied across to `F2`"Sleep" and all copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER($A2),LOWER(D$1),"")))/LEN(D$1)
```

3] `G2` "Keywords" , formula copied down:

```
=LOOKUP(ROW(A1),SUMIF(OFFSET(C$1,,,ROW($1:$12),),"<>")+1,B$2:B$4)&""
```

4] `H2` "Occurrence", formula copied down:

```
=IF(G2="","",COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2))
```

5] `I2` "Content Keyword Data Text", formula copied down:

```
=IF(G2="","",LOOKUP(H2,SUMIF(OFFSET(INDEX($1:$1,MATCH(G2,$1:$1,0)),,,ROW($1:$12),),"<>")+1,$A$2:$A$12))
```

6] `J2` "Position", formula copied down:

```
=IF(G2="","",FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(I2),LOWER(G2),"~",COUNTIFS(G$2:G2,G2,I$2:I2,I2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bosco_Yip, thank you so much for your provided formula improvement to getting the actual results for finding the Position for each line, thank you again, it works... I really appreciate your assistance and cooperation in considering this daunting task...